# Exit Criteria Status

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We're trying to trouble shoot a contact who meets our exit criteria but is still in  a journey. It's looking a a particular field on our contact audience containing a Y value however they're not exiting. There aren't multiple rows per contact for the journey entry data extension.

What should the status be for an ExitCriteriaActivity where they meet the criteria and are exited? I can't seem to find anything on [the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_status_key_reference.htm&type=5)

Comment: What criteria are you using to determine the contact has not exited?  I just went thru troubleshooting of an issue that occured due to outages 2 weeks ago.  There was a Marketing Cloud issue that caused failure to retrieve email address from Contact during determination of sendability and it looked like the Contact just got stuck at a certain step.

Comment: Unfortunately they received the next email in the journey. Looking at the journey history they're still in the journey at a wait activity.

Comment: I think you will have to open a support case with Marketing Cloud.